# Как создать поле в модели из другой таблицы?

Tags: php, yii

Предположим, имею связь многие-ко-многим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу ли я создать в модели `main` поле под `elem.name`?

Comment: Нет. И учитывая связь Many-To-Many, алгоритм вычисления его значения не определен.

Comment: ну то есть id элемента то я знаю. может каким sql запросом?

Comment: des1roer, это вы знаете идентификатор, а не фреймворк. Вы, конечно, можете прибегнуть к магии с `getElemName()` для создания виртуального атрибута, но у вас, похоже, XY problem, и вы решаете абсолютно не с того конца.

Comment: @des1roer Пожалуйста, избегайте добавления метки в заголовок вопроса. Для указания тематики вопроса достаточно перечислить необходимые метки в отведенном для этого поле.

Comment: ник учту. а создать в модели абстрактное поле из другой модели я могу? или realtions - это единственный образ связи?